# Want to create csv file and write to csv file using multiple different arraylists

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have 5 `ArrayList`s at the moment:

```
ArrayList <String> name;
ArrayList <Integer> age;
ArrayList <Integer> salary;
ArrayList <String> address;
ArrayList <String> occupation;
```

I essentially want to create CSV file within the directory and write whatever is in the array into each section of CSV file. So I want first row to have name and then whatever is in name `ArrayList`, repeat for the second row with age and the second `ArrayList`.

I tried something like this but CSV file does not get created in my folder directory:

```
File csvFile = new File("tst.csv");
PrintWriter out =  new PrintWriter(csvFile);
for (String s:name){
    out.println(s);
}
out.close();
```

Comment: Does `name` contain any elements? Try putting `System.out.println(s);` as the first line in the `for` loop to verify whether that loop is executing. Alternatively, if you are using an IDE, try running your code with the IDE debugger. And maybe consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: Ya name does contain elements in it. Also the CSV file itself does not get created within files directory